# How to update state of parent's parent component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm playing around with fb's tutorial on comment box. Let's imagine I've added functionality to delete comments, so I will have something like this in Comment component -

```
onClick={this.handleCommentDelete}
```

How do I trigger change of the state of the commentBox parent component without propagating callback throughout commentList component and then to comment component?

```
<commentBox>
  <commentList>
    <comment>
```

Comment: Flux architecture is one way of doing this. Call a `ActionCreators.deleteComment` action in `this.handleCommentDelete`. `Dispatcher` dispatches it to all stores. `CommentStore` acts upon the action by deleting the comment and emits change event. `CommentBox` which is listening to the `CommentStore` updates itself with the new list of comments.

Comment: It's partly a question of what component actually "owns" the act of deleting the comment. Is it the base level `Comment` component? Or some container that does? Events are a very efficient and extremely clear way of transmitting state through a parent chain and establishes a clear owner. You might then use the Flux pattern ...

Answer (score 0):

I am using PubSub pattern to communicate between components. In commentBox:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    PubSub.subscribe("COMMENT_DELETED", function( msg, data ){
        console.log( data ); //logs "commentId"
    });
}
```

In handleCommentDelete:

```
PubSub.publish("COMMENT_DELETED", {commentId: commentId});
```

For PubSub I am using this library (but there are others of course): https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js.